# Dear ImGui without window in the window

Tags: c++, imgui

Normally in ImGui, even without `ImGui::Begin("Blah blah window title")`, it will display a
window inside of the desktop window. e.g.:
[window in a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BluLc.png). How can I make it more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyG2A.png).
Note: I'm a total noob at ImGui, so if this is completely against the idea of ImGui I wouldn't be surprised.

I was unable to find many answers to my questions because they were flooded with answers on how to use ImGui without a NORMAL window, and not a window in a window.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you want, but it seems like you'd want to set flags so you'd call `ImGui::Begin("window name", 0, ImGuiWindowFlags::NoTitleBar | ImGuiWindowFlags::NoResize`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.